# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: EngineConfig.getLogRollingSize()

Tags: birt

I am a newbie in BIRT, have installed Eclipse Birt plugin 4.3 and downloaded OSGI birt-runtime-osgi-4_3_0,
i have a standalone program to open the sample report in the birt runtime envt. but i am getting error

at
    conf = new EngineConfig();
    conf.setEngineHome("C:/birt-runtime-osgi-4_3_0/ReportEngine");
    //Create new Report engine based off of the configuration
    eng = new ReportEngine( conf ); -----------> Error.

as

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig.getLogRollingSize()I
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.intializeLogger(ReportEngine.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.<init>(ReportEngine.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory.createReportEngine(ReportEngineFactory.java:14)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportEngine.<init>(ReportEngine.java:71)
    at com.pg.o2.test.synch.ReportTest.main(ReportTest.java:33)
```

,

thought of running a stand alone pgm and start with JBOSS ,

please let me know if anything i have to download or missign jars.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the jars in the runtime haven't been referenced in your eclipse project as [described here](http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/21858-null-pointer-exception-while-starting-the-engine/).  Are you running the application from eclipse or deploying it and getting these errors.  If you're in eclipse go to the project settings and add the jars from the runtime to the build path.  If you're getting these while deployed the jars need to go in your lib folder.